# Eclipse/JFace - Adding views in a wizard dialog

Tags: eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I am working on an Eclipse plugin and I want the wizard page to dynamically display views. Is there any way we can achieve this? Please help.

Comment: What do you mean by 'dynamically display views'? Do you mean you want to open a view in the main Eclipse window or what?

Comment: @greg-449 I know the way to display views in the main Eclipse window. I am trying to do the same in an Eclipse Wizard window, but couldn't achieve it. Is there a way to display a view inside a wizard?

Comment: you should create a common UI component and use it in View or Wizard. View or Wizard are like containers for UI components.

Answer (score 1):

There is no support for displaying a view in a wizard (or any dialog).

Comment: Is there a way to divide the wizard into multiple parts (similar to views in the main eclipse window) and update them dynamically? Apologies if the question is trivial, I am new to eclipse RCP and couldn't find any helpful source for my requirement.

Comment: You can't use any of the Eclipse view / editor mechanisms in a wizard. You can use SWT controls such as `Sash` and `SashForm` So, yes you can have things that update, but how you code it is up to you.